# Google Maps Navigation ETA Distinguishes Lanes?

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone know if Google Maps distinguishes lines on jammed crossroads when displaying ETA (estimated time of arrival) for your current route? I frequently travel on roads that are marked as red (or even black) because lane for turning left (or right) is completely full. But I am not going to turn, I am on lane to continue straight which is completely empty. Google shows that I am on the red road.

Can Google Maps tell the difference between the lanes and project it into the ETA? My guess is it does not.

Why I am asking this is when I travel by car, I use Google Maps to get around the city faster (comparing different alternatives in the rush hour). But if it cannot differentiate the jammed and empty lines then I know I cannot rely on ETA for alternatives too much and go with what I think is faster.

Comment: That’s off-topic on [su]. No, it doesn’t. If there’s a single line, that’s how Google analyzes traffic on this road.

Comment: this will get closed as off-topic, however - this is a notorious bit of the North Circular in London, which demonstrates the only way Google can differentiate - the slip-road is only considered a 'different road' at the point it separates from the main - even though the left turn lane is actually about a mile long & starts at the previous junction … & can be jammed solid along its entirety, while the outside lane is relatively clear - https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5810209,0.0408637,16z/data=!5m1!1e1